SQL to parse very long string into many columns
How to use base SQL to parse a very, very long string into many columns by a delimiter?
I’ve been through a few posts (here for example, and here or here) on parsing into separate columns, rows, et cetera. They all however seem to manually identify and create each column. (Here, for example, the example includes three columns, the maximum number needed). I need up to 90 columns. I’m looking for a way to consolidate, or functionalize, the parsing into multiple columns so I don’t need to repeat the equivalent of ‘,nullif(split_part(my_string,'|',N),'') string_N’ from below 90 times.
with test_data (id, my_string) as
(
    select 1, 'a|b|c|d' union all
    select 2, 'abba|zabba|beta' union all
    select 5, 'x|y' union all
    select 4, 'z1|z2|z3'
)
select 
    id 
    ,nullif(split_part(my_string,'|',1),'') string_1 
    ,nullif(split_part(my_string,'|',2),'') string_2 
    ,nullif(split_part(my_string,'|',3),'') string_3 
    ,nullif(split_part(my_string,'|',4),'') string_4 
from test_data ;

I tried building the solution manually, as above. Doing it for very, very long strings would create problems for me. The posted SQL solutions aren't getting there and I can't use python.

Please mark your RDBMS version

You're supposed to avoid storing deliminted data in a single column in the first place, so yes, this is gonna be painful. It's also gonna resplit the entire string from scratch for each column, and again for every single row, so don't expect to run very fast, either.

Also, I inferred an Oracle DB based on the from dual (every other DB has been smart enough to not need that for pushing 30 years now), but the split_part() function is an amazon or postgresql thing. So you should take the correct DB yourself.

Your question is tagged Oracle but all the questions you link to are tagged SQL Server - none of the answers there are going to work on Oracle and the code you include in the question will give the exception ORA-00904: "SPLIT_PART": invalid identifier because it isn't a valid function fiddle. Are you sure you are using Oracle?

I know @JoelCoehoorn you edited (it looks like that was you?) the tags to show Oracle. I'm using SQL in Snowflake, and I posted this as a standalone SQL coding question. If the 'from dual' throws people, maybe I should change that.

https://asktom.oracle.com/ords/asktom.search?tag=clob-and-blob-datatypes

So no, @MT0 , this isn't an Oracle question ! Thanks for flagging.

Please edit your question reflect the correct RDBMS and remove any syntax that's not valid.  Also, since you are using Snowflake, if this data is coming in files, look into schema on read/infer schema

"Standalone"  tag means ISO/ANSI SQL. I.e. nullif and string_part aren't available.

Hi  - what’s wrong with just using the SPLIT function? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split

Taking pivot based technique a little further and combining it with some scripting, we can get around the problem of having to use "'column_name'" instead of just column_name.
--dummy data
create or replace temporary table t (id, my_string) as
select 1, 'a|b|c|d' union all
select 2, 'abba|zabba|beta' union all
select 5, 'x|y' union all
select 4, 'z1|z2|z3';

--start with a clone
create or replace temporary table t_split clone t;

--add additional varchar columns (string_1 through string_N) dynamically
declare
  rs resultset;
  num_cols int;
  cols_def varchar;
begin
  num_cols:= (select max(regexp_count(my_string,'[|]')) from t_split) + 1;
  cols_def:= (select regexp_replace(array_to_string(array_generate_range(1,:num_cols+1),','),'([0-9]+)','string_\\1 varchar'));
  rs:= (execute immediate 'alter table t_split add column '||:cols_def);
  return table(rs);
end;

--insert to table
insert overwrite into t_split

with cte as
(select a.*, b.index as cols, b.value 
 from t a, lateral split_to_table(my_string,'|') as b)

select *
from cte
pivot (max(value) for cols in (any order by cols))
order by id;

--take a look
select * from t_split;


Excellent @kathmundude, this works well too! Thank you

In Snowflake, you can achieve this in 3 steps: split the column into an ARRAY, flatten the array into rows, and use a dynamic PIVOT to move the rows back into columns.
CREATE TABLE  test_data (id, my_string) as
(
    select 1, 'a|b|c|d' union all
    select 2, 'abba|zabba|beta' union all
    select 5, 'x|y' union all
    select 4, 'z1|z2|z3'
);

WITH str_to_arr AS (
    SELECT 
        id 
        , SPLIT(my_string, '|') as split_
    FROM test_data
),

flattened_data AS (  -- changed 'flattened' to 'flattened_data' for consistency 
    SELECT
        id
        , f.value as column_value
        , 'column_' || f.index as column_name
    FROM str_to_arr
         , lateral flatten(input => str_to_arr.split_) f
)

SELECT *
FROM flattened_data
     PIVOT(
        MIN(column_value)
        FOR column_name IN (ANY ORDER BY column_name)
        DEFAULT ON NULL('')
     )
ORDER BY id
;

Result:
| ID | 'column_0' | 'column_1' | 'column_2' | 'column_3' |
|----|------------|------------|------------|------------|
|  1 | a          | b          | c          | d          |
|  2 | abba       | zabba      | beta       |            |
|  3 | z1         | z2         | z3         |            |
|  4 | x          | y          |            |            |

The performance of this approach will vary on the shape and size of your data. For better performance, you should pre-process this data or split it into columns on ingest.

Fantastic. @Teej I owe you a drink.

@chriseshleman happy to help!

Save one CTE by using STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE. See documentation at https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_split_to_table
